# How to set icon in dxSlideOut,Devextreme

Tags: javascript, view, icons, devextreme, tabslideout

I've used dxslideout in some parts of the Devextreme basic project

.dxView

```
<div data-bind="dxSlideOut: {
dataSource: musteriNavItems
}"> 
.
. 
</div>
```

javascript

```
musteriNavItems = [
{ action: "Profil", icon: "profil", text: "Profil" },
{ icon: "info", text: "Çıkış" }
];
```

These codes work.Text appears in dxSlideOut design,but icons do not appear on this design.
How do I add icons beside the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default dxSlideOut item template does not support the 'icon' field. So, you can use the [menuTemplate](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxSlideOut/Default_Item_Template/?version=15_1#menuTemplate) option to define icon for a menu item.

```
<div data-options="dxTemplate:{ name:'menuItem' }">
     <span data-bind="attr: {'class': 'dx-icon-' + icon}"></span>
     <span data-bind="text: text"></span>
</div>
```

I've created a small fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/dfc2ggck/1/

Also, be sure your icon exists in the [DevExtreme Icon Library](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Themes/Icon_Library/?version=15_1#Icon_Library).

Comment: Hi Sergey, dxTemplate structure was solved my problem.Thanks for the answer.